# Add frequent tab for tags in Android app

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app

Tags are very useful for finding your [interested topics](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics). Whenever I find any interesting tag, I used to visit `frequent` questions on it.

But I've found that the Android app doesn't have the frequent tab for tags.

[image: screenshot]

In other words, `frequent` tab looks missing in the Android app.

So, I'm requesting to add `frequent` tab in mentioned drop-down list for searching through tags.